# Dynamic allowed length in kendoMaskedTextBox

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-maskedtextbox

I need to use **kendoMaskedTextBox** to allow user type 3-4 numbers and **prevent** to type more. And I don't want to get spaces in value.

When user enters 123, I need to get 123. I don't want to get 123_. 
I need to get it as value, because I'm using Knockout with Kendo controls, there is no way how to use **raw** function to strip mask.

So I need to set mask like `000_` but get rid of space in value.

Is it possible?

Comment: Did you checked if you can manipulate its value inside the `change` event before knockout reads it ?

Comment: Maybe it is possible, but I'm looking for pure Kendo solution. If there is any way how to set minimum and maximum input value for example. There are rules and masks, but nothing more. I can create custom binding and read raw value from Kendo, but still, first asking :-)

Comment: Well, there is nothing like that in its [docs](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/maskedtextbox) so I'm afraid you will have to implement it by yourself.